# Faraday::SSLError and "certificate verify failed"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, outlook, openssl

I am working on Windows 10. I want to create application which will be using the outlookAPI. So I was following Getting started tutorial at [Write a Ruby on Rails app to get Outlook mail](https://dev.outlook.com/restapi/tutorial/ruby).

I've faced of this issue of *`SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed`* as shown below;

[image]

Issue above appears when I try to `getToken` after the authentication stage went successfully.

I would be appreciated of any suggestions.

Comment: Two requests.. (1) Please state the errors. The text on the picture is too small to read. In addition, the text cannot be indexed by search engines for future visitors. (2) Please post the URL you are using to connect to the server, and post the output of `openssl s_client -connect <hostname>:<port> -tls1 -servername <hostname> | openssl x509 -text -noout`. Do so by adding it to your question by clicking *Edit* (and don't post it as a comment). Otherwise, we can't reproduce it and there's not enough information to help troubleshoot it.

Comment: I don't know how you created your certificate, but ***`CN=example.com`*** is probably wrong. Hostnames always go in the *SAN*. If its present in the *CN*, then it must be present in the *SAN* too (you have to list it twice in this case). For more rules and reasons, see [How do you sign Certificate Signing Request with your Certification Authority](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21340898/608639) and [How to create a self-signed certificate with openssl?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10175812/608639)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding gem 'certified' in your gemfile and run bundle install.

```
gem 'certified'
bundle install
```

Comment: I tried to run 'gem install 'certified', bundle install, but unfortunately it doesn't work.